# I get org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetCheckCondition@51e0b99a when running query against virtuoso on jena API

Tags: spring-boot, sparql, jena, virtuoso

I am using the Virtuoso Jena provider and I have I am using spring boot to deploy the program to tomcat server. In the request parameters I send the whole query and I execute it against Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint. The problem is that when I query something of the form:

```
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> 
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/data/>
SELECT ?p  ?o  WHERE {ex:PCBBoard2 ?p ?o}
```

I get `org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetCheckCondition@51e0b99a`

But when I query something like that:

```
PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> 
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/data/>
SELECT ?s  ?o  WHERE {?s sosa:observes  ?o}
```

I get the correct response with the results which is :

```
[{FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/windSensor14, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/windSpeedLocation4687}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/iphoneSpeedSensor, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/iphoneSpeed}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/tempSensor23, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/tempSensor23temperature}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/VCAB-DP1-BP-40, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/VCAB-DP1-BP-40groundDisplacementSpeed}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/Appartment134Sensor926, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/Appartment134electricConsumption}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/DHT224578, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/Room145temperature}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/DHT224580, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/Room245temperature}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/BMP282Sensor, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/BMP282SensorAtmosphericPressure}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/DHT224581, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/Room245humidity}, {FunVar(s)=http://example.org/data/DHT224579, FunVar(o)=http://example.org/data/Room145humidity}]
```

I am sending the requests with `postman`.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String query(@RequestParam String thequery) throws UnirestException {
        Reasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();
VirtGraph vg = new VirtGraph("http://147.27.60.65/sensorOntology", "jdbc:virtuoso://147.27.60.65:1111", "dba", "boto");
            Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/>\r\n" + 
                    "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n" + 
                    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                    "CONSTRUCT FROM <http://147.27.60.65/sensorOntology> WHERE {?s ?p ?o}");


            QueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, vg);

            Model model1 = vqe.execConstruct();
            Graph g = model1.getGraph();
InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel( reasoner, model1 );
            //Query sparql1 = QueryFactory.create("PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {?s sosa:actuationEnabled ?o }");
            Query sparql1 = QueryFactory.create(thequery);

            QueryExecution qe = SparqlDLExecutionFactory.create(sparql1, infModel);
            ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
qe.close();
            return results.toString();
}
```

Don't mind the reasoner `VirtGraph` and `CONSTRUCT` parts that is working correctly and is for reasoning the graph stored on Virtuoso the actual query is happening here:

```
InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel( reasoner, model1 );
Query sparql1 = QueryFactory.create(thequery);

            QueryExecution qe = SparqlDLExecutionFactory.create(sparql1, infModel);
            ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
                        qe.close();
            return results.toString();
```

`thequery` is supposed to be the query sent as String in `@RequestParam`

Comment: what do you expect to see when calling `results.toString();`? I mean, `toString()` isn't implemented, you will just see the Java object type. So my question, what should `toString()` do for you? Either you iterate over the `ResultSet` (yes, it is an iterator, nothing more nothing less), or you use convenience methods like `ResultSetFormatter.asText(results)` to see some meaningful string rendering of the result.

Comment: I edited the post with the correct response. As I can actually see the results returned with the second query

Comment: To answer your question I want it to return the whole result set as JSON so I return it as string and spring boot automatically turns it onto JSON(?? that is what I have understood from documentation and messing around)

Comment: `[{FunVar(s) ...` must come from the Pellet SPARQLDLEngine as I've never seen `FunVar` in native Jena. Nevertheless, `ResultSetCheckCondition` is just a wrapper around `ResultSet` - seriously, you should use the Jena API to convert the resultset to JSON. Please try `ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(outputStream, results);

// and turn that into a String
String json = new String(outputStream.toByteArray()); return json;` - this should directly return the resultset as SPARQL JSON

Comment: I managed to find the correct way and made the comment before seeing your comment but thanks anyway. Now the output is as you say the correct SPARQL JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I managed to get a good representation by changing:
`return results.toString();`
to

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
QueryExecution qe = SparqlDLExecutionFactory.create(sparql1, infModel);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(b, results);
qe.close();
return b.toString();
```